# NoSuchFieldError: WHITESPACE while restarting weblogic admin

Tags: weblogic12c

NoSuchFieldError: WHITESPACE while restarting weblogic admin

We have upgraded weblogic from 12.2.1.3 to 12.2.1.4. After weblogic upgrade, when we have restarted weblogic admin, then below error is thrown in logs. Due to this application GUI login page is not opening.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WHITESPACE
        at com.google.template.soy.soytree.TemplateNode.parseSoyDocDescHelper(TemplateNode.java:390) ~[soy-2012-12-21.jar:?]
        at com.google.template.soy.soytree.TemplateNode.<init>(TemplateNode.java:260) ~[soy-2012-12-21.jar:?]
        at com.google.template.soy.soytree.TemplateBasicNode.<init>(TemplateBasicNode.java:255) ~[soy-2012-12-21.jar:?]
        at com.google.template.soy.soytree.TemplateBasicNode.<init>(TemplateBasicNode.java:94) ~[soy-2012-12-21.jar:?]
        at com.google.template.soy.soyparse.SoyFileParser.Template(SoyFileParser.java:296) ~[soy-2012-12-21.jar:?]
        at com.google.template.soy.soyparse.SoyFileParser.SoyFile(SoyFileParser.java:261) ~[soy-2012-12-21.jar:?]
        at com.google.template.soy.soyparse.SoyFileParser.parseSoyFile(SoyFileParser.java:176) ~[soy-2012-12-21.jar:?]
        at com.google.template.soy.soyparse.SoyFileSetParser.parseSoyFileHelper(SoyFileSetParser.java:219) ~[soy-2012-12-21.jar:?]
        at com.google.template.soy.soyparse.SoyFileSetParser.parseWithVersions(SoyFileSetParser.java:170) ~[soy-2012-12-21.jar:?]
        at com.google.template.soy.soyparse.SoyFileSetParser.parse(SoyFileSetParser.java:152) ~[soy-2012-12-21.jar:?]
        at com.google.template.soy.SoyFileSet.compileToTofu(SoyFileSet.java:571) ~[soy-2012-12-21.jar:?]
        at com.google.template.soy.SoyFileSet.compileToTofu(SoyFileSet.java:553) ~[soy-2012-12-21.jar:?]
        at com.tcs.bfsarch.tags.eh.html5.BfsMessagesTagHtml5.getSoyRenderer(BfsMessagesTagHtml5.java:147) ~[coreweb.jar:?]
        at com.tcs.bfsarch.tags.eh.html5.BfsMessagesTagHtml5.getErrorContent(BfsMessagesTagHtml5.java:60) ~[coreweb.jar:?]
        at com.tcs.bfsarch.tags.eh.bfsMessagesTag.doEndTag(bfsMessagesTag.java:181) ~[coreweb.jar:?]
        at jsp_servlet._common.__dologin._jsp__tag45(__dologin.java:2475) ~[a325ov/:?]
        at jsp_servlet._common.__dologin._jspService(__dologin.java:2221) ~[a325ov/:?]
        at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:35) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.4]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:295) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.4]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.4]
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137) ~[com.oracle.weblogic.servlet.jar:12.2.1.4]
```

Please note that with weblogic 12.2.1.3, there is no such issue.

Comment: The class com.google.template.soy.soytree.TemplateNode is part of a Google java lib which is not bundled with WebLogic. Check the java libs used by env (12.2.1.3 and 12.2.1.4) to locate this lib. Maybe your are using to different versions of this java lib that can explain the exception.

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin : Since I've both the below jars in my classpath :  guava-12.0.jar and soy-2012-12-21.jar which contains all required classes. But still nto sure why its throwing NoSuchField error during when I try to open login page of GUI screen. Please suggest if any jar needs to be upgraded guava jar or any other thirdparty jar. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the class com.google.template.soy.soytree.TemplateNode present in both libs ?

Comment: This com.google.template.soy.soytree.TemplateNode class present in soy-2012-12-21.jar is present only in my Online/lib  folder. Its not present in Webllgic lib and Oracle lib path. Do we need to place this jar in weblogic lib also ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved as there was class loading conflict for “com.google.common.base”  (guava-12.0.jar). The same was being loaded from WLS as well. Added the following entry in weblogic-application.xml.

org.apache.commons.lang.*

```
<package-name>com.google.common.collect.*</package-name>
<package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</package-name>
<package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
<package-name>com.google.common.io.*</package-name>
<package-name>com.google.common.base.*</package-name>
```

org.apache.commons.lang.*

```
<resource-name>com.google.common.collect.*</resource-name>
<resource-name>org.apache.log4j.*</resource-name>
<resource-name>org.slf4j.*</resource-name>
<resource-name>com.google.common.io.*</resource-name>
<resource-name>com.google.common.base.*</resource-name>
```

Due to wls(weblogic) upgrade from 12.2.1.3 to 12.2.1.4, we had this issue in our application.

Thanks for the time and support.